# Where is "Call forwad" in marshmallow (Android 6)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, huawei

It seems its absoultely crazy question but really i cannot find answer:
after update my phone to android 6, it seems in the call forwarding setting is missed in setting menu! i also search it using filed button but i cannot find it, could anyone help me about the situation in this version? i have Huawi P8Lite. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you looked in the dialer/phone app settings itself to see if the option is there?  On my S7 Edge the option is there, but that dialer/phone app is most likely different from Huawi's.

Comment: Many Thnaks RMarkwald, Yes here it finally found. as you told in Dial Pad Setting. Thanks again. unfortunately i cant mark tour commect as best answer until you put it in the answer area. but let me know if you do that for remarking it as the best answer. :)

Comment: Added answer.  Glad you found it!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the Dialer/Phone app settings itself to see if the option is there. On my S7 Edge the option is there, but that Dialer/Phone app is most likely different from Huawi's.